# Send Email From Application Hosted On Local Server

Tags: email, cakephp, smtp, cpanel

I have orangescrum installed on both local server and cloud server. When I try to send E-mail to other user from local server the mail is not getting delivered. I have checked the SMTP configurations, all seems fine. I checked email track delivery on cpanel but no email is shown.

I want mail server hosted on cloud to accept those emails originated from my local server and send it to the destination email address. It seems like something is blocking the request. Should I have to configure(DKIM,SPF etc) anything on cpanel so that it accept my mails? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to use your cpanel server as "smarthost" for your local server.

In cPanel you can do it in [this way](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/setup-server-as-a-smarthost.405892/):

> You can add the IP address/hostname of the local server (public IP) to the
> following options in "WHM Home » Service Configuration » Exim
> Configuration Manager":
>
> - "Trusted SMTP IP addresses"
> - "Backup MX hosts"
>
> In some cases you may need to add the IP address to the
> /etc/alwaysrelay file and enable Antirelayd.

Comment: Thank you masterguru. It was the exact answer I'd been searching for. As Exim Configuration Manager wasn't enabled on my cpanel, I contacted the support team and found that we have hosted the application on a shared server and it is not possible to enable the Exim Configuration Manager on our server.
Any alternative solution is much appreciated.

Comment: Ops, well, my mistake, I missunderstood you had a server access so you could reach Exim configuration. Maybe you still have a solution. I guess you already read the FAQ about SMTP of orangescrum here: https://helpdesk.orangescrum.com/faq/ (search for SMTP) and have followed their steps that talks about gmail account. Right?  Just try to change that values to your domain instead gmail. (I guess you already did, just in case).

Comment: I followed these steps but still it wasn't working. Seems like my domain server is refusing to accept the request on SMTP port 25.
Also tried to use gmail server using sendgrid but that wasn't worth.
Fortunately, PHPMailer did the work. I couldn't use my own domain mail server, but PHPMailer and gmail server is doing the work now. 
Thanks alot..Your answer was valuable.

Comment: mmm.. in this case try to use 465 or 587 port instead the port 25. Just to know if this is possible.